# Exception TypeError warning sometimes shown, sometimes not when using throw method of generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator

There is this code:

```
class MyException(Exception):
  pass

def gen():
  for i in range(3):
    try:
      yield i
    except MyException:
      print("MyException!")


a = gen()
next(a) 
a.throw(MyException)
```

Running this code:

```
$ python3.3 main.py
MyException!
$ python3.3 main.py
MyException!
Exception TypeError: TypeError('catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed',) in <generator object gen at 0xb712efa4> ignored
$ python3.3 main.py
MyException!
$ python3.3 main.py
MyException!
$ python3.3 main.py
MyException!
Exception TypeError: TypeError('catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed',) in <generator object gen at 0xb714afa4> ignored
```

The thing which I don't understand is why sometimes there is printed this `Exception TypeError` warning. Is there something wrong with custom exception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are seeing a  `__del__` hook misbehaving somewhere.

The `TypeError` is being thrown while *shutting down*, as the Python interpreter is exiting everything is deleted and any exceptions thrown in a `__del__` deconstructor hook are being ignored (but *are* printed).

On exit, Python clears everything in the namespace by rebinding everything to `None`, but the order in which this happens is not set. The still running generator is closed (`a.close()` is called) when deleted, which triggers a `GeneratorExit` exception in the generator, which Python tests against your `except MyException:` line. If, however, `MyException` has *already* been cleared up and Python sees `except None:` the `TypeError` is thrown and you see that message printed.

You can trigger the error without exiting Python by adding:

```
MyException = None
del a
```

If you use `list(a)` and consume the rest of the generator, or explicitly close the generator with `a.close()` before Python exits and deletes `MyException`, the error message goes away.

Another work-around would be to handle `GeneratorExit` first:

```
def gen():
  for i in range(3):
    try:
      yield i
    except GeneratorExit:
      return
    except MyException:
      print("MyException!")
```

and Python will not evaluate the next `except` handler.

The error cannot be reproduced with Python 3.2 or earlier, so it looks like [hash randomization](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#builtin-functions-and-types) (introduced in Python 3.3) randomizes the order objects are cleared; this certainly explains why you see the error only on *some* of your runs, but not on earlier Python runs where the hash order is fixed.

Note that the interaction of `.__del__()` hooks and other global objects in Python is documented with a big red warning in the [`.__del__()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Warning**: Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

Comment: in python 2.7 the warning is never shown and code posted is the only code in the file.

Comment: Python 3.2 also doesn't print that.

Comment: With `del`, the much more logical NameError is raised.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Because then the exception is not rebound to `None`. I've updated my answer to better reflect that. :-)

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to execute python code after rebinding a bunch of names to `None`.

Comment: This is not limited to generators. This has the same problems: http://pastebin.com/FLDfePS6

Comment: @PavelAnossov: This is well-documented, see http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__

Comment: @PavelAnossov: I knew about the behaviour of `__del__` and exceptions being printed to `stderr` already, which is why I realised that the error was being shown on shutdown and that it must be related to object deletion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: right, so it's not because of generator changes in 3.3, it's just something about the deletion order changed.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Perhaps; the deconstructor has been closing generators explicitly since [PEP 342 was implemented](http://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/b2fe5f8fcfdd/Objects/genobject.c), so it appears that that is not it. I now suspect it is the [hash randomization](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703) that causes the order of deletion to change randomly.

Comment: I feel less safe now :) The general advice "do not use `__del__`" is now extended with "be aware that some of your code may get called from some built-in `__del__` and everything about `__del__` applies to it". Another advice is "do not leave unclosed generators around".

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know one shouldn't normally leave comments like this but...figuring this one out is *extremely* impressive! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same error in Python 3.3 on Windows, with the difference that I was defining the exception in its own file. These were my code files:

```
$ cat FooError.py 
class FooError(Exception):
    pass

$ cat application.py
import FooError
try:
    raise FooError('Foo not bar!')
Except FooError as e:
    print(e)
```

This was the exception that I was getting:

> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed.

**Changing `import FooError` to `from FooError import *` resolved the issue. Here is the final code, for clarity's sake:**

```
$ cat FooError.py 
class FooError(Exception):
    pass

$ cat application.py
from FooError import *
try:
    raise FooError('Foo not bar!')
Except FooError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Would have worked if you just Except FooError.FooError since you can't catch the module :)

Comment: @GuyL: Thanks! I don't have a Windows machine to test, but I suppose that `from FooError import FooError` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - but I was missing the import to the exception class. So the interpreter didn't resolve the class on the except clause.

So just add the import and hopefully everything will work.