# Python Requests Mock doesn't catch Timeout exception

Tags: python, python-requests, python-mock

I wrote a unittest to test timeout with the requests package

my_module.py:

```
import requests

class MyException(Exception): pass

def my_method():
    try:
        r = requests.get(...)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        raise MyException()
```

Unittest:

```
from mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

from my_module import MyException

@patch('my_module.requests')
class MyUnitTest(TestCase):
    def my_test(self, requests):
        def get(*args, **kwargs):
            raise Timeout()

        requests.get = get

        try:
            my_module.my_method(...)
        except MyException:
            return

        self.fail("No Timeout)
```

But when it runs, the try block in `my_method` never catches the `requests.exceptions.Timeout`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems I see here. One that directly fixes your problem, and the second is a slight misuse of the Mocking framework that further simplifies your implementation.

First, to directly address your issue, based on how you are looking to test your assertion, what you are actually looking to do here:

```
requests.get = get
```

You *should* be using a `side_effect` here to help raise your exception. Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> side_effect allows you to perform side effects, including raising an
>   exception when a mock is called

With that in mind, all you really need to do is this:

```
requests.get.side_effect = get
```

That should get your exception to raise. However, chances are you *might* face this error:

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

This can be *best* explained by actually reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31873937/1832539) great answer about why that is happening. With that answer, taking that suggestion to actually only mock out what you *need* will help fully resolve your issue. So, in the end, your code will actually look something like this, with the mocked `get` instead of mocked `requests` module:

```
class MyUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('my_module.requests.get')
    def test_my_test(self, m_get):
        def get(*args, **kwargs):
            raise Timeout()

        m_get.side_effect = get

        try:
            my_method()
        except MyException:
            return
```

You can now actually further simplify this by making better use of what is in unittest with `assertRaises` instead of the try/except. This will ultimately just assert that the exception was raised when the method is called. Furthermore, you do not *need* to create a new method that will raise a timeout, you can actually simply state that your mocked get will have a `side_effect` that raises an exception. So you can replace that entire `def get` with simply this:

```
m_get.side_effect = Timeout()
```

However, you can actually directly put this in to your patch decorator, so, now your final code will look like this:

```
class MyUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('my_module.requests.get', side_effect=Timeout())
    def test_my_test(self, m_get):    
        with self.assertRaises(MyException):
            my_method()
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`patch('my_module.requests')` will replace `my_module.requests` with a new mock object, but in your test method you replace the `requests.get` method of the directly imported and therefore on the original requests module, which means that change is not reflected within your module.

It should work if in your test method you replace it on the requests mock within your `my_module` instead:

```
my_module.requests.get = get
```