# Python 3 handling error TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Tags: python, exception, typeerror, binance

When I run this code:

```
i=0
while i<5:
    i=i+1;
    try:
        SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
    except client.get_order as e:
        print ("This is an error message!{}".format(i))
#End while
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

I read this tread [Exception TypeError warning sometimes shown, sometimes not when using throw method of generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163697/exception-typeerror-warning-sometimes-shown-sometimes-not-when-using-throw-meth/18163759#18163759) and this one [Can't catch mocked exception because it doesn't inherit BaseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713054/cant-catch-mocked-exception-because-it-doesnt-inherit-baseexception) also read this https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/a-very-picky-except-in-python-d9b994bdf7f0

I kind of fix it with this code:

```
i=0
while i<5:
    i=i+1;
    try:
        SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
    except:
        print ("This is an error message!{}".format(i))
#End while
```

The result it's that ignores the error and go to the next while but I want to catch the error and print it.

Comment: Since this question popped up high in my search - in my case the error was caused by my simple mistake, instantializing the error class, i.e. `except TypeError():` instead of `except TypeError:`.

Comment: Same for me as with @Czechnology - in my case i wrote by accident `def myException(Exception)` vs `class myException(Exception)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I post the [question](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216562/python-3-handling-error-typeerror-catching-classes-that-do-not-inherit-from-bas) in Spanish Stack with better results.
To translate and sum up:
The error occurs because in the exception clause you must indicate which exception you capture. An exception is a class that inherits (directly or indirectly) from the base class Exception.

Instead I have put client.get_order where python expected the name of the exception, and what you have put is a method of an object, and not a class that inherits from Exception.

The solution goes this way

```
try:
    SellSta=client.get_order(symbol=Symb,orderId=SellOrderNum,recvWindow=Delay)
except Exception as e:
    if e.code==-2013:
        print ("Order does not exist.");
    elif e.code==-2014:
        print ("API-key format invalid.");
    #End If
```

You'll need to code for every exception in [here](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/errors.md)

Comment: I'm using PyMongo 3.8, and it says `object has no attribute 'code'`, so I did this instead:
except Exception as err:
 if "already exists" in err._message:
  pass

Comment: @BenjiA. Is the issue solved? If yes, how did you handled the error?

Comment: @PrabhuKhannaMahadevan ..you could just do something like `if hasattr(e, "code"): # do_stuff_with_code_attribute_here` if you'd like to check if the error object has the `code` attribute first.

Comment: I also got this error when doing `except queue.Empty():` instead of `except queue.Empty:`  which is what I actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Another case when it may happen because the except clause in Python expects either a single exception class or a tuple of exception classes. Using a list directly is not valid syntax.

**Wrong**

```
try:
   something()
except [Exception1, Exception2] as e:
   process_exception(e)
```

**Correct**

```
try:
   something()
except (Exception1, Exception2) as e:
   process_exception(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are importing the exception correctly. For example, if you are using sockets, `except timeout` won't work except you are importing the `timeout` exception:

`from socket import timeout`